# Property of Subadditive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Call a sequence $\left \{ a_n \right \}$, $n \geq 1$, strictly subadditive if it satisfies the inequality
$$
a_{n+m} < a_n+a_m
$$
for all $m$ and $n$. I am wondering whether it is necessarily true that a positive strictly subadditive sequence satisfies
$$
\frac{a_n}{n}>\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}.
$$ 
All the examples I've come up with so far satisfy this property (e.g., the functions $\sqrt{n}$, $1$, $n+1$). Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a_1=1,a_2=1/3, a_3=1/2$. Assume that we have constructed the first $n\geq 3$ terms so that
$$
a_{n}<a_r+a_s
$$
holds for all $r,s\in\mathbb N$ with $r+s=n$. Define
$$
a_{n+1}=\min \{(a_r+a_s)/2\in\mathbb R|r+s=n+1\}.
$$
This way we inductively construct a strictly subadditive sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $a_1=1,a_2=1/3,a_3=1/2$. Now,
$$
a_3/3=1/6=a_2/2,
$$
giving you a counter example.

Edit: Alternatively, you can take $a_1=1,a_2=0,a_3=1/2$ and $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 4$. However, the construction above gives you a strictly positive, strictly subadditive sequence.